# In Mercurial, is it exactly the same doing "hg vdiff -r -2:-3" and "hg vdiff -c -2"?

Tags: mercurial

Because I used to always do

```
hg vdiff -r -2:-3
hg vdiff -r 5213:5212
```

are all the `hg` commands exactly the same using those, vs using

```
hg vdiff -c -2
hg vdiff -r 5213
```

?

Answer (score 2):

The -c option means changes introduces by this revision, so `hg foobar -c 23` is the same as `hg foobar -r22:23` if 22 is the first parent of 23. When 22 and 23 are not in a parent0-child relationship, you get the diff of two random changesets.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hg help revisions` to see all the various ways you can specify revisions, which should work with all subcommands.